# Orthogonal complement of diagonal matrices

Tags: inner-products

My question is similar to this one:

[Orthogonal complement of the diagonal matrices in the inner product space of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392466/orthogonal-complement-of-the-diagonal-matrices-in-the-inner-product-space-of-mat)

> Considering $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with inner product $\langle A,B \rangle = \text{tr} (AB)$. Describe the orthogonal complement of the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with all the diagonal matrices.

So my thoughts are similar to the ones of @LiúJiāgěng. The orthogonal complement of the subspace $U \le V$ consisting of the vectors of the space $V$ that verify $\langle u,v\rangle=0$ for all $v$. Therefore, the only matrices that verify this for all the diagonal matrices are the matrices with only zeros in the diagonal.

Can you please verify if I'm right? I don't know if that user's answer is correct or not, because nothing was said about it, nor was it upvoted.
Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer, but surely something more should be said here to justify "therefore". One way to do this is to pick a basis $(E_a)$ of the diagonal matrices and see what conditions $\langle E_a, A \rangle = 0$ imposes on a general matrix $A$.